# How to read binary file until the end-of-file?

Tags: java, binaryfiles, eof

I need to read binary file including the `eof`.

I read file using `DataInputStream`

```
DataInputStream instr = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream( fileName ) ) );
```

And I used `readInt();` to read binary file  as an integer.

```
try {
    while ( true){
        System.out.println(instr.readInt());
        sum += instr.readInt(); //sum is integer
    }
} catch ( EOFException  eof ) {
    System.out.println( "The sum is: " + sum );
    instr.close();
}
```

But this program doesn't read the End-of-file or last line of text(if it's text file).
So if the text file is only contained only one line of text, the sum is 0.
Please help me with this.

Example: if `.txt` file containing the text.

```
a
b
c
```

`readInt();` just only reads `a` and `b`.

Comment: Maybe I misundertood you, but there is no "end-of-file" character to be read.

Comment: Please explain: _So if the text file is only contained only one line of text, the sum is 0._

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but I think _DataInputStream_ is the wrong choice. Do you want to read a list of numbers line by line?

Comment: if i use this program in .txt file. this program doesn't read last line of text..

Answer (score 3):

That's indeed normal. You are trying to read the bytes, and not ints. The `readInt()` method melts four bytes together to an int.

Let's analyse your example file:

```
a
b
c
```

This is totally 5 bytes: `a`, `\n`, `b`, `\n`, `c`.
`\n` are newlines.

The `readInt()` method takes the four first bytes and makes an int of it. This means when you try to make a second call to it, there is only one byte left, which is not enough.

Try to use `readByte()` instead, which will return all the bytes, one by one.

---

To demonstrate, this is the body of the `readInt()` method, it calles 4 times `read()`:

```
   public final int readInt() throws IOException {
        int ch1 = in.read();
        int ch2 = in.read();
        int ch3 = in.read();
        int ch4 = in.read();
        if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
        return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
    }
```

When the end of a file is reached, `-1` is returned from the `read()` method. That is how EOFExceptions are detected.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it might be better to use a Reader and use .next() and .nextLine()

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader );
String sum;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  sum += scanner.next()) {
}
reader.close();
System.out.println( "The sum is: " + sum );
```